# How to find where a stack overflow occured in lisp?

Tags: lisp, clisp

I'm getting: `*** - Program stack overflow. RESET` running some lisp in the REPL. I have seen various suggestions on how to modify stack size but... how do I just find what function is causing the overflow?

Comment: how about using some of the usual debugging tools? Backtrace, TRACE, Step, ...?

Comment: Doesn't it put you into the debugger when this happens? You should be able to use the debugger's backtrace command to show the stack, and the function with infinite recursion should stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear to put me in the debugger. It seems to reset the REPL. I'm presented with just another REPL prompt numbered 1. I'm guessing that's what the RESET means?

Comment: That is the debugger prompt, most likely.

Comment: No, it's not the debugger prompt. Since if I try to run debugger commands like Backtrace, it gives error: `*** - EVAL: variable Backtrace has no value
The following restarts are available:`

Comment: have you tried reading the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is running under `gdb` and setting a break in `SP_ueber` and using `call back_trace_out(0,0)` when the breakpoint is reached.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is probably no, or at least not easily.

See this: [Re: stack overflow -> into debugger?](http://osdir.com/ml/lisp.clisp.general/2002-02/msg00114.html)

Comment: The message you link to answers a _different_ question: how to detect an _impending_ stack overflow, not how to _debug_ an _actual_ SO.

Comment: The discussion there seemed to indicate to me that the runtime does not have a way to debug an actual SO because at that point there is no stack to run anything to debug it.